# Changes to block quotes in the pipeline

Tags: discussion, design, formatting

For some reference as to how [block quotes](http://research.wou.edu/mla/mla-blockquote) used to look like on EL&U before the the theme was overhauled, see [English Language & Usage's updated site theme is ready for testing!](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11707/44619) and [Make blockquotes inside blockquotes better distinguishable](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7804/make-blockquotes-inside-blockquotes-better-distinguishable/7813#7813) .

**Pre-December, 2018**

[image]

**Since December 2018**

[image]

According to a [Meta announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343919/some-improvements-to-blockquotes) dated February 19, 2020, this will soon change.

> ## Some improvements to blockquotes
>
> We’re making a few changes to blockquotes soon. […]
> We’re proposing we switch to a single gray bar in our blockquotes. This should fix those theming issues and make it easier to distinguish between quotes, spoilers and code.
>
> This will also improve blockquote nesting, since our current nesting is a mess because the darker yellow bar is barely noticeable on the paler yellow background.

An example of how the proposed change will look:

[image]

<sub>(Yes, I could've cropped it better)</sub>

Apparently the grey sidebar is used on similar sites

[image]

The text says:
*There is a lot of prior art out there for this approach. GitHub has styled theirs this way for a long time. So has Slack*

On EL&U, which has a yellow theme,  it should look something like this

[image]

The above is a cropped image taken from a much larger one found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npLwJ.png).

The Stack Developer/employee, Aaron Shekey♦ concludes with this message.

> Let me know what y’all think. I think these changes will be an improvement, and I hope you do too.

Well, seeing as many users on EL&U are probably unaware of the proposal, because I haven't seen any announcement on EL&U meta,  please make yourself heard on META (Stack Exchange) and post what *y'all think*.

Comment: I noticed this on Meta. I already downvoted the Q and all the *pro* answers, and upvoted all the *contra* answers, including the currently highest-voting answer. I often *deliberately* use block quotes *because* they have color, in order to organize and structure answers, which is particularly important for my longer answers. That is, my favorite ones. People need to be able to **see**, at a glance, that a long answer has structure, to avoid the wall-of-text TL;DR effect.

Comment: Why are they changing the look of blockquotes instead of fixing the backlog of bugs with them?

Comment: And it's happened :-(

Comment: @AndrewLeach while entire Italy is in the red zone...

Comment: Yes, well, it wasn't when I wrote that. (And it may well affect me, although there's a bit of time before I have to call on the travel insurance.)  Bit of a surprise! Hope it doesn't make life too difficult. Stay well.

Comment: @AndrewLeach it wasn't meant to be a criticism, just a somewhat wry nod to reality. I am well... I live and normally work alone, and in small groups. Thank you for saying.

Comment: Stay well, @Mari-LouA. As for the bars instead of the blocs, I couldn't care less. However, I must admit to being a bit piqued with a description as _English Language and Usage's "resident" authority_. I'm not sure whether it's the distinction or the scare quotes that bemuses me more.

Comment: @JohnLawler the situation in the North West of Italy, where I live, is dramatic. The death toll rises and yet people get sick, people fall and break their limbs, ambulances must be called but there is a shortage of beds, and some hospitals are even quarantined. I have just spent 5 hours at an Emergency Room, outside, because relatives are not allowed to travel with their loved ones in ambulances, visitors are not allowed in ER but must wait outside, outdoors preferably. Today there was a magnificent blue sky and I thought, what if this were the last day, the last day of my being healthy?

Comment: Luckily the patient could go home, but there were no ambulances left, so I took her back home in my own car. An 88-year-old woman, my dearest aunt, whose children all live in London with their families and because of the lockdown cannot go and visit her. There must be hundreds of stories similar to mine, every day, for the last two weeks. It's so bad, You might have an inkling of what to expect with the Covid19, but until you actually experience it the self isolation, you won't understand.

Comment: Update: The region where I live is orange; the pandemic, and the now semi-isolation,  no movement allowed between regions unless for work or health continues.

Answer (score 10):

Why the [expletive deleted] would anyone think that removing the different background color from blockquotes is in any way, shape, or form a good idea? Just because everyone else is jumping off a cliff doesn't mean we should, too.

Don't tell me "because theming", because any theme worth the name will have a contrast background color available.

Grrr.

Comment: I can see I'm going to have to brush up on my userscripting to change the CSS.